# Gmail API using multiple labelIds

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am trying to access Gmail using its API on Python. I want all the `UNREAD` messages , only from `INBOX`.

I can call either:

```
GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds='INBOX').execute()
```

or:

```
GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds='UNREAD').execute()
```

However, calling both the `labelIds`doesn't work. Can someone help with using both the `labelIds` simultaneously.

TIA

Comment: How were you calling both labelIds?

Comment: I tried different methods. Added a comma `(UNREAD,INBOX)` and `labelIds='UNREAD',labelIds='INBOX'`

Comment: Ok, try the solution I just posted and please accept if it is working.

Comment: Multiple `labelIds` will definitely not work.  I would try `labelIds = ['UNREAD', 'INBOX']`.

Comment: @sailesh Thanks.. It works, but is not filtering correctly. I am getting messages from 'Promotions'/'Updates' tabs as well

Comment: @chhibbz I think, you are talking about the category not labels. Promotions/Updates are categories. They are not Labels. Updated my solution to filter the category to only primary.

Answer (score 2):

> I want all the UNREAD messages , only from INBOX.

`UNREAD` and `INBOX` aren't really "labels".  Try the `q` parameter instead like:

```
GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='in:inbox is:unread').execute()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Gmail assumes AND between query parameters so it will return messages that are in the Inbox and are unread. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190.

Answer (score 1):

labelIds can be a single string or it can be a python List of strings.

Something like this:

```
GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds=['UNREAD', 'INBOX']).execute()
```

Filter the category to only show emails from primary in Inbox which are unread.

```
 GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds=['UNREAD', 'INBOX'], q="category:primary").execute()
```

Comment: And here is why: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#list

Comment: This will return messages that are in Inbox  OR are unread. Grisha's answer is the route you want to take (using q to query).

Comment: @Jay Lee, labelIds: string, Only return messages with labels that match all of the specified label IDs